# This is an endpoint for an API, but I'm having problems with the insertion of the month and year in the url.. How can I improve it?

Tags: python, psql

This is not wotking at the moment and with the insert of the month and year I need to get the best 10 product sales of a certain month. How can i improve this and work on it?This is an API for a supermarket.

```
@app.route('/report/month_product/<year-month>', methods = ['GET'])
```

is {} or <>??

```
def product_results(year, month):
   logger.info('GET /report/month_product/')
   

   conn = db_connection()
   c = conn.cursor()

   try:
       c.execute('''
                   SELECT count(product_id), PRODUCT_ID, SUM(product_purchase.price) as "valor total"
                       FROM product_purchase, purchase 
                       WHERE product_purchase.purchase_id = purchase.id 
                       AND data between '%s-%s-01' AND date '%s-%s-01' + interval '30 days'
                       GROUP by PRODUCT_ID
                       ORDER BY COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) DESC
                       LIMIT 10;;''')

       rows = c.fetchall()

       row = rows[0]

       logger.debug('GET /report/month_product/<year-month> - parse')
       logger.debug(row)
       content = {'count': int(row[0]), 'product_id': row[1], 'valor_total': row[2]}

       response = {'status': StatusCodes['success'], 'results': content}

   except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
       logger.error(f'GET /report/month_product/<year-month> - error: {error}')
       response = {'status': StatusCodes['internal_error'], 'results': str(error)}

   finally:
       if conn is not None:
           conn.close()

   return flask.jsonify(response)
```

I'm new on stack but I'm glad if you can help me, I'm learning how to build api's and databases with pSQL and python